# Same Height Columns With CSS Tables - Paragraph Tag Breaks Equality

Tags: html, css

I am trying to give 2 columns the same height no matter what using a CSS Tables:

`display: table` and `display: table-cell`

The problem I've encountered is that if I do not have at least 1 paragraph tag in my content, the "table cells" do not fill out. My question is, why is this the case? Why does the paragraph tag ( or lack there of ) trigger Column Equality?

**Edit**

The purpose of the CSS Tables and `height: 100%` is so that both columns can have a dynamic height and both columns have the same height. So any kind of static height would solve the issue but overall defeat the purpose of the CSS Table.

**Code Blocks :: Working**

```css
main {
    display: table;
    height: 100%;
    width: 1200px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

main #sidebar,
main #content {
    display: table-cell;
    height: 100%;
}

#sidebar {
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
    width: 225px;
    border: 1px solid #A8A9AD;
    background: #E8E9EB;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #FFF 0%,#E8E9EB 60%);
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #FFF 0%,#E8E9EB 60%);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#ffffff', endColorstr='#e8e9eb',GradientType=0 );
}

#content {
    float: right;
    width: 925px;
}
#content h1.post-title {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 8px 0 12px 0; 
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
#content hr.clear {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

```html
<main>
 <aside id="sidebar">
  Sidebar
 </aside> <!-- id="sidebar" -->
 
 <article id="content">
  <h1 class="post-title">Page Title</h1>
  
  <hr class="clear" />
  
  <h1>First shalt thou take out the Holy Pin</h1>
  <p>No, no, no! Yes, yes. A bit. But she's got a wart. Shut up! Will you shut up?! I'm not a witch. She looks like one. Oh, ow!</p>
  <h2>I'm not dead!</h2>
  <p>And the hat. She's a witch! Shh! Knights, I bid you welcome to your new home. Let us ride to Camelot! Where'd you get the coconuts? He hasn't got shit all over him.</p>
  <ul>
   <li>Camelot!</li>
   <li>Knights of Ni, we are but simple travelers who seek the enchanter who lives beyond these woods.</li>
   <li>Well, I didn't vote for you.</li>
   <li>Burn her anyway!</li>
  <li>We want a shrubbery!!</li>
  </ul>
  <h3>How do you know she is a witch?</h3>
  <p>On second thoughts, let's not go there. It is a silly place. The Knights Who Say Ni demand a sacrifice! Well, how'd you become king, then? Burn her anyway! Camelot! It's only a model.</p>
  <h4>How do you know she is a witch?</h4>
  <p>And this isn't my nose. This is a false one. Knights of Ni, we are but simple travelers who seek the enchanter who lives beyond these woods. Well, I got better. Where'd you get the coconuts? It's only a model.</p>
  <ol>
   <li>The Knights Who Say Ni demand a sacrifice!</li>
   <li>Be quiet!</li>
   <li>Bring her forward!</li>
  </ol>
  <h5>Bridgekeeper</h5>
  <p>We want a shrubbery!! It's only a model. Well, I didn't vote for you.</p>
  
 </article> <!-- id="content" -->
  <div class="clear"></div>
</main>
```

**Code Blocks :: Broken**

```css
main {
    display: table;
    height: 100%;
    width: 1200px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

main #sidebar,
main #content {
    display: table-cell;
    height: 100%;
}

#sidebar {
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
    width: 225px;
    border: 1px solid #A8A9AD;
    background: #E8E9EB;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #FFF 0%,#E8E9EB 60%);
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #FFF 0%,#E8E9EB 60%);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#ffffff', endColorstr='#e8e9eb',GradientType=0 );
}

#content {
    float: right;
    width: 925px;
}
#content h1.post-title {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 8px 0 12px 0; 
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
#content hr.clear {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

```html
<main>
 <aside id="sidebar">
  Sidebar
 </aside> <!-- id="sidebar" -->
 
 <article id="content">
  <h1 class="post-title">Page Title</h1>
  
  <hr class="clear" />

        <div>Ni !</div>
        <div>Ni !</div>
        <div>Ni !</div>
        <div>Ni !</div>
        <div>Ni !</div>
        <div>Ni !</div>
        <div>Ni !</div>
        <div>Ni !</div>
        <div>Ni !</div>
        <div>Ni !</div>
        <div>Ni !</div>
        <div>Ni !</div>
        <div>Ni !</div>
        <div>Ni !</div>
        <div>Ni !</div>
        <div>Ni !</div>
        <div>Ni !</div>
        <div>Ni !</div>
        <div>Ni !</div>
        <div>Ni !</div>
  
 </article> <!-- id="content" -->
  <div class="clear"></div>
</main>
```

I've created some JSFiddles to show what I mean:

[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3fhark1k/)

[Broken Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/426h9uyL/1/)

Comment: Why do you need float (esp. for `#content`) if you display it as table-cell? And I checked examples in jsfiddle - it looks for me like they're the same in firefox. Or perhaps I do not understand the question right...

Comment: @SergiyT. The reasoning for the floats was pretty much to give space between the two "cells". And you're right I hadn't x-browser checked these fiddles it doesn't seem to work properly in FF but in Chrome it shows a different result.

Comment: If you remove float and add padding for space will it solve the problem? Currently I do not have Chrome installed so just guessing here...

Comment: @SergiyT. That's the solution, Thanks! If you post an answer I'll accept it, otherwise I'll have to leave my answer up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you remove float and add padding for space will it solve the problem?

I think that floats are not well suitable for the table-like displays. 
And it may not display right in different browsers.

Answer (score 0):

Set a max-height on them. You could use a min but if you wan't it to be responsive leave the height: 100% in.

//CSS

```
main {
    display: table;
    min-height: 100%;
    width: 1200px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
main #sidebar,
main #content {
    display: table-cell;
    min-height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: The purpose of putting them in a CSS Table and giving height 100% is so that the height is dynamic and both columns will reflect the others height. By adding a max-height it would defeat the purpose, I would be better off putting `height: 200px;`. I tried min-height but it doesn't seem to solve the issue.

Comment: Okay you re-phrased the question I know what you mean now so your problem to clarify is that if there isn't any content inside the table/cell I.E. a "paragraph" then it doesn't scale out... Set the a minimum height of 100%, then so that even if it's empty it will still fill the same amount space.

Comment: There's content in both cells, the working one has paragraphs and the broken one has it's content in `<div>`'s instead, which is the core of my question as to *why* it works with paragraphs and not div's since both are block level tags. That being said, `min-height: 100%` also doesn't seem to work on my broken fiddle ( linked at bottom of question ).

Comment: Ok I know what you mean. Your calling the TableBlock (PARENT) as the main element... What you have to do is leave main as the structure of the document... and create (2) separate tables with (child) cell block.. I create a jsfiddle link with a different model which will be way more easy for you.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [Sergiy T.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/882073/sergiy-t) I was able to find the solution. I guess the problem had to do with floating the "cells", while both *could* be floated it would break the height of the table ( even if cleared apparently ). The solution had to do with **not** floating one of the cells.

**The Solution**

Remove *float* from `#sidebar` but give it a `vertical-align: top`. Problem solved!

```css
main {
    display: table;
    height: 100%;
    width: 1200px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

main #sidebar,
main #content {
    display: table-cell;
    height: 100%;
}

#sidebar {
    vertical-align: top;
    text-align: center;
    width: 225px;
    border: 1px solid #A8A9AD;
    background: #E8E9EB;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #FFF 0%,#E8E9EB 60%);
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #FFF 0%,#E8E9EB 60%);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#ffffff', endColorstr='#e8e9eb',GradientType=0 );
}

#content {
    float: right;
    width: 925px;
}
#content h1.post-title {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 8px 0 12px 0; 
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
#content hr.clear {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

```html
<main>
 <aside id="sidebar">
  Sidebar
 </aside> <!-- id="sidebar" -->
 
 <article id="content">
  <h1 class="post-title">Page Title</h1>
  
  <hr class="clear" />

        <div>Ni !</div>
        <div>Ni !</div>
        <div>Ni !</div>
        <div>Ni !</div>
        <div>Ni !</div>
        <div>Ni !</div>
        <div>Ni !</div>
        <div>Ni !</div>
        <div>Ni !</div>
        <div>Ni !</div>
        <div>Ni !</div>
        <div>Ni !</div>
        <div>Ni !</div>
        <div>Ni !</div>
        <div>Ni !</div>
        <div>Ni !</div>
        <div>Ni !</div>
        <div>Ni !</div>
        <div>Ni !</div>
        <div>Ni !</div>
  
 </article> <!-- id="content" -->
  <div class="clear"></div>
</main>
```